# On the equality of certain proper and improper integrals.

Tags: calculus, integration

For any *complex valued*, nonconstant and differentiable $f$, is it possible that

$$ Im \int_0^1 f(x) \mathrm{d}x = Im \int_1^\infty f(x) \mathrm{d}x  $$

Presently i seem not to have any idea on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Define $f(x) = i\sin^2(\pi x/2)$ for $x\in [0,2],$ $f(x) = 0$ elsewhere. Then $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and

$$\int_0^1\text { Im } f(x)\, dx = \int_0^1 \sin^2(\pi x/2)\, dx = \int_1^2 \sin^2(\pi x/2)\, dx = \int_1^\infty\text { Im } f(x)\, dx.$$